# Use a vector method to prove that the triangle is isoceles.

Tags: geometry, vectors, triangles

If two medians of a triangle are equal then prove by vector method that it is an isosceles $triangle$
This might be a simple question but i could not do it because i don't know any theorems related to vector.

Comment: The way to start seems obvious: express the sides of your triangle using vectors, then work to express the medians as vectors, then see what the hypothesis gives you.

Comment: Apollonius' theorem in effect gives $m_a^2=\frac14(2b^2+2c^2-a^2)$ and $m_b^2=\frac14(2a^2+2c^2-b^2)$ which makes it very easy to show $m_a=m_b \implies a=b$.  Apollonius' theorem can be proved with vectors and the diagonals of a parallelogram

Comment: What _do_ you know about vectors? It will not be much use to answer the question if the answer relies on facts you don't know yet.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for. Name $v,w$ the two vectors in the directions of the two sides of the triangle with half of the lenght.

[image]

The vectors of the two medians can be expressed by $-2v+w$ and $-2w+v$. They are equal in lenght, so
$$|-2v+w|=|-2w+v|$$
that can be rewritten using dot product
\begin{align}
(-2v+w)\cdot (-2v+w) &=(-2w+v)\cdot (-2w+v) \\
4|v|^2-4w\cdot v+|w|^2 &= 4|w|^2-4w\cdot v+|v|^2 \\
3|v|^2&=3|w|^2.
\end{align}
Hence $|v|=|w|$ and the triangle is isosceles.

Comment: The vectors of the two medians are $-2v+w$ and $-2w+v$.

Comment: I have edited it.

Comment: @user236182 Thank you!